# I/O manipulator bug or temporary lifetime extension by const ref?

Tags: c++, reference, object-lifetime, iomanip

I tried to wrap the io manipulator `std::put_money`.  Here's a reduced illustration:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

long double scale(long double f) { return f * 100.0L; }

namespace acm {

auto put_money(const long double &f, bool intl = false) {
  return std::put_money(scale(f), intl);
}

}

int main() {
  long double f(1234.567L);
  std::cout << "1: " << acm::put_money(f) << '\n';
  std::cout << "2: " << std::put_money(scale(f)) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
1: -92559631349317829570406876446720000000000000000000000000000000
2: 123457
```

I dug into both MSVC and libc++'s guts and learned that `std::put_money` returns a custom type that *keeps a const reference* to the value rather than making a copy.

Line 1 could be wrong because the reference is invalid when the custom object is streamed (i.e., the temporary value returned by `scale` inside my `acm::put_money` is already destructed).

Q:  But then, why is line 2 correct?

Theory 1:  "Bad luck."  Keeping a const reference to the temporary is a bug, but it just so happens that the value still exists on the stack, possibly because it wasn't trampled by the extra function call.  (This is supported by the fact that a Release build generally works, presumably because the extra function call is inlined.)

Theory 2:  Lifetime extension of the temporary by the const reference is helping in the second case, but, for some reason, it doesn't apply in the first case.  Perhaps the extra function call breaks the rules for lifetime extension?

Theory 3:  ???

Comment: I note that [cppreference's writeup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money) explicitly states that `std::put_money` is defined only when used in an expression which applies the return value of `std::put_money` to the formatted output operator on `std::ostream`. Based on that, line 1 is undefined behavior.

Comment: That's an _answer_ as you should know.

Answer (score 1):

Finally located where in the standard this is specified (slightly edited for readability):

> [ext.manip]
>
> `template <class moneyT> unspecified put_money(const moneyT& mon, bool intl = false);`
>
> `Requires:` The type `moneyT` shall be either long double
>   or a specialization of the `basic_string` template.
>
> `Returns:` An object of unspecified type such that if out is an object of type
>   basic_ostream then the expression `out << put_money(mon, intl)`
>   behaves as a formatted output function that calls
>   `f(out, mon, intl)`, where the function `f` is defined as:
>
> [ example omitted ]
>
> The expression `out << put_money(mon, intl)` shall have type
>   basic_ostream& and value `out`.

The long and the short of it is that `std::put_money` is only defined when it is on the right hand side of the `<<` formatted output operator with the left hand side being a `std::basic_ostream`. Only your line 2 meets that requirement, and line 1 does not.

Comment: I think it'd be an improvement to the standard if it explicitly mentioned that other usages are not defined (and compilers could warn/error about it).

Comment: Hmm.  You're reading more restrictions into that section than I think are actually written there. It describes how the returned object will behave in a stream insertion operation, but it doesn't seem to say you cannot do other things with it.  For example, it doesn't say you can't copy the object (as in, `auto x = std::put_money(mon, intl); std::cout << x << '\n';`).  For other "objects of unspecified type" I see in the standard, restrictions on copying and moving tend to be made explicit.

Comment: Also, my wrapper should get the guaranteed return-value optimization, so the only thing done with the object is to directly pass it as the second argument of the insertion operator.  The only significant difference is that the const ref it contains is no longer valid.

Comment: Return value optimization has absolutely nothing to do whatsoever with anything here. The issue in question is a lifetime of a parameter to a function call two nested levels of calls in. `main` calls a function. That function computes a temporary value and passes it as a parameter to `std::put_money`, and returns. Whether or not RVO takes place, or not, that parameter to `std::put_money` is no more. It's gone to meet its maker. It's pining for the fjords. It's an ex-parameter. It's long gone after the function call returns (with or withour RVO), and then something happens that depends on it.

Comment: "but it doesn't seem to say you cannot do other things with it." -- that's not what a standard is for. It's not a description of things that ***can't*** be done. It's only a description of things that ***can*** be done. It doesn't say, for example, that the following construct is valid: "for (while x(4->7); switch)". You won't find anything in the standard that you cannot do that. Doesn't mean that you can. `std::put_money` is not defined as a standalone class or function, but only in the context of an output stream operation.

Comment: I think it behooves us not to conflate `std::put_money` with the "object of unspecified types" it returns.  The quoted passage describes how the _returned object_ will behave in a stream-insertion operation, and it guarantees that there will be such an overload of the stream-insertion operator.  I don't see anything that says the library implementers can use a fragile reference that prevents the user from using the object to get the described behavior. "that [argument] to `std::put_money` is no more":  Right.  But what keeps the temporary alive in the second case?

Comment: The rule that says that temporary values go out of scope at the end of the expression. These library implementations seem to comply with the standard, which only defines their usage in this very specific and narrow expression. You have no other defined behavior for these library functions. To a trained, experienced eye, it is quite clear that the quote I gave, from the standard, defined only this specific usage, and not one bit more. The wording used there is very dry and strict.